# libidn build .a and .so lib giving different result

Tags: c, unicode, normalization, .a

I am trying to use GNU libidn, compiled from source code. If I build my application with `libidn.so`, the function is working fine. (Only interested in the function `stringprep_profile()`. This function is using for the unicoded password normalization.)

However, when I tried to build with `.a` file, the same input got the segmentation fault. Kind of confused right now.

Comment: the dynamic linking is correctly getting any dependent shared libs, while the static compilation may be pulling in older code with bugs?

Comment: The problem is the looking table for the saslprep. It is a .h file generated by a perl script. The script has bugs which I tested, it gave me 2 different result ran in Redhat vs MacOs. The latest script seems solve the bugs..... Anyway, it is solved now.  Thanks. @MarkEssel